# How to correctly resize photo using plugin.media for xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use xamarin.forms plugin.media plugin to take a photo and save it at a specific size. Here's my code:

```
private async void ButtonPhoto_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable && CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        var mediaOptions = new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Custom,
            MaxWidthHeight = 250,
            Directory = "MyFolder",
            Name = _item.Id + ".jpg",
            SaveToAlbum = true
        };

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(mediaOptions);
    }
}
```

The actual saving of the photo to the desired folder works, however, the resizing options are being ignored. I want the picture width to be set at no more than 250 pixels. Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

edit 1:

I also tried the following, but still no joy:

```
var mediaOptions = new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
    MaxWidthHeight = 250,
    Directory = "MyFolder",
    Name = _item.Id + ".jpg",
    SaveToAlbum = true
};
```

edit 2:

Tried the following using RotateImage as suggested, but still no joy:

```
var mediaOptions = new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Custom,
    RotateImage = true,
    CustomPhotoSize = 5,
    Directory = "MyFolder",
    Name = _item.Id + ".jpg",
    SaveToAlbum = true
};
```

edit 3:

Tried setting RotateImage with MaxWidthHeight, but still not working:

```
var mediaOptions = new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
    MaxWidthHeight = 150,
    RotateImage = true,
    Directory = "MyFolder",
    Name = _item.Id + ".jpg",
    SaveToAlbum = true,
    CompressionQuality = 75
};
```

Comment: Just take a look at the source ... [you have to set RotateImage to true](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/src/Media.Plugin.Android/MediaImplementation.cs#L203) (just see what FixOrientationAndResizeAsync and what ResizeAsync does)

Comment: I tried using RotateImage as suggested (see edit 2 in the OP) but still not working.

Comment: no ... read the code again ... RotateImage true + MaxWidthHeight = some value

Comment: Still not working, see edit in OP.

Comment: @lepton did you got this working ever?

Comment: @Ashish - unfortunately not. I ended up using some code to do the resizing after the media plugin had created the image.

Comment: @lepton, would you care to show what code you ended up using? I'm using the plugin as well - but having issues with resizing (and especially the decoding the image after having base64 encoded it..)

Answer (score 1):

The SaveToAlbum option always stores the original photo in full resolution locally.

The image resize is only applied in the returned MediaFile.GetStream() data.

So you could deactivate SaveToAlbum and store it manually using the provided data stream.

In my case I had to send the image over a network connection. The behaviour full size on local storage and resized in app stream was handy in my case.